# Python 3 PhotoImage repeats across label when rendered more than once

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Python 3 Tkinter program that is supposed to render an image from a special file format.

```
from tkinter import *

image = []

path = Tk()
display = Toplevel()

display.wm_title("RCSVvisual")
display.wm_iconbitmap("favicon.ico")

path.wm_title("RCSVpath")
path.wm_iconbitmap("favicon.ico")

entry1 = Entry(path)
entry1.pack(side=LEFT)

photo = PhotoImage(width=240, height=180)

def refresh():
    file_path = entry1.get()
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            thisLine = line.strip()
            thisArray = thisLine.split(",")
            image.append(thisArray)

    for c1 in range(0, len(image)):
        for c2 in range(0, len(image[c1])):
            photo.put(image[c1][c2], (c1, c2))

button = Button(path, text="Open File", command=refresh)
button.pack(side=LEFT)

label = Label(display, image=photo)
label.pack()

path.mainloop()
display.mainloop()
```

And this is the file I test it out on:

```
#F00,#0F0,#00F,#F00
#0F0,#00F,#F00,#0F0
#00F,#F00,#0F0,#00F
#F00,#0F0,#00F,#F00
```

However, it appears that if you run the program more than once, the image does not replace the old one; instead displaying to the right of the original image. Am I doing something wrong here? Should I .pack() the target label again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always appending to `image`.

If you want to create new image, you should empty existing list first.

```
def refresh():
    image = []
    file_path = entry1.get()
    ....
```

Also, *almost always* you'd need only one mainloop in your program. You should remove `display.mainloop()` line.